# Live performance of Aerosmith's Mama Kin with the introduction solo

Tags: rock-n-roll

I'm currently learning to play Mama Kin by Aerosmith on the guitar. I'm especially interested in Joe Perry's intro solo. I watched several introductory videos where people explain how to play it, but there are parts where I'm not sure if Joe Perry plays it like they do.

I watched several Youtube videos of live performances of Mama Kin by Aerosmith. However, in all the videos, they skip the intro solo and start directly with the verse.

Is there a recording of a live performance with the solo?

Comment: Welcome to Music.SE! For this question, you may have better luck at [MusicFans.SE](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/).